# Highcharts: Generate chart from tables having linked data

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a table where data values are wrapped with an `<a>` tag. [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) plugin is used to generate a pie chart from that table. But for some reason it is not showing/ generating. If I remove link from data values, then it works fine. Is there any way to generate the pie chart while keeping the links?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#chart-cont').highcharts({
    data: {
      table: 'datatable',
    },
    chart: {
      type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
    },
  });
});
```

```css
#chart-cont {
  min-width: 310px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>

<div id="chart-cont"></div>

<table id="datatable">
  <tr>
    <th>Colors</th>
    <th>Values</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Blue</th>
    <td><a href="#">40</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Black</th>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Green</th>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You ever find a solution for this? I have a similar issue.

Comment: i updated the code and found a somewhat working example but it does not seem to strip the other columns. jsfiddle.net/6e2bfdk8/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a `data.parsed` function ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data.parsed)) which removes the link from the column before using it in a series. For your table an example could be:

```
data: {
    parsed: function(columns) {
        // Loop over all the values from the table
        for(var i = 0; i < columns[1].length; i++) {
            // Strip away HTML content
            columns[1][i] = parseInt(stripHTML(columns[1][i]));
        }
    }
}
```

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e2bfdk8/6/) for an example use of this. I'll leave it up to you to find the best way to alter the columns to remove the anchor tag.

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/822452/2732991) for good ways to remove HTML from a string, and their disadvantages.

Comment: The fiddle does not work. You ever get this working?

Comment: i updated the code and found a somewhat working example but it does not seem to strip the other columns. https://jsfiddle.net/6e2bfdk8/5/

Comment: @Aaron thanks for the notice. I've updated the JSFiddle in my answer to work. Regarding your example, just strip all the value-columns, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/6e2bfdk8/8/

Comment: You are a god among men!!!! ok last question but a tough one. This is a real world example data https://jsfiddle.net/6e2bfdk8/13/. Also what is I only need to show specific columns like 1,3 and 4?

Comment: i tried using the complete option and slice but does not work https://jsfiddle.net/6e2bfdk8/17/

Comment: @Aaron not sure how you would want to present it, but at least this gets the values in there: https://jsfiddle.net/6e2bfdk8/25/

Comment: This is AWESOME!!! You ROCK! How easy is it to specify only specific columns to use for the data and also why does it say "Series 1" and "Series 2" rather than using the TH's and using "Revenue Charged" and "Capacity" from the table header? You have been such a huge help!

Comment: @Aaron Bit of an index error. You could just splice several times. See https://jsfiddle.net/6e2bfdk8/31/. Venturing quite far away from original question so you'll have to ask a question if you continue having issues with your specific case.

Comment: SPECTACULAR!!! You are amazing and thank you soooo much! You get an upvote for being a great person and helping with this! :)