# Looping inside JavaScript parameter

Tags: javascript, highcharts, parameters

Using [Highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/) plugin, I tried to [generate a pie chart from table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34455783/3377130) data. But it is not working, as table values are wrapped with `<a>` tags. Probably next easiest solution can be storing table values into an `array`. Then use that data-array to generate pie charts. As number of table rows, cells, values, etc. may alter, so I am finding a dynamic solution that will turn that `array` into parameter-value pair. Something like [following](https://jsfiddle.net/armikbd/2vdvur9L/),

```
data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 1
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]
```

So, actually I am trying to use loops for `name`, `color`, `y` etc.

---

#### Edit: More clarification

I am looking for functions something like below.

```
var names = ['Point 1', 'Point 2'];
var colors = ['#00FF00', '#FF00FF'];
var y =[1 , 2]

function tableData(){
    for (i=0; i<=1; i++ ) {
        name: names[i],
        color: colors[i],
        y: y[i]
    }
}

data: [tableData()]
```

Comment: I think you forgot to ask a question

Comment: The last line is my ultimate goal and question as well. I do not want, (and not possible) to repeat `name`, `color` etc. over and over again.

Comment: As far as I understand - Highcharts convert an HTML Table to pie chart - So you must generate the table.
therefor I dont quite understand what you are trying to do - please clarify

Answer (score 0):

Probably my question was not clear enough. However I was able to solve my problem.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/2vdvur9L/) was my initial script where data were directly put into function.

```
data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 1
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]
```

In the [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/armikbd/2vdvur9L/2/), data comes from arrays. Those arrays can be created from HTML tables easily.

```
var names = ['Point 1', 'Point 2'];
var colors = ['#00FF00', '#FF00FF'];
var y = [1, 2]

var data1 = [];
for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
    obj = {
      name: names[i],
      color: colors[i],
      y: y[i]
    };
    data1.push(obj);
}
```